# eDirectory: Exception in Settings.php line 79: Cannot find host localhost for this eDirectory installation

Tags: php, symfony, arcasolutions-edirectory

I get this error when I visit any page (`http://localhost:8000/config.php`) of a customized eDirectory app.

```
2/2
Exception in Settings.php line 79:
Cannot find host localhost for this eDirectory installation

in Settings.php line 79
at Settings->setActiveHost('localhost') in Settings.php line 38
```

With a 29 line stack trace. This is line 38

```
    $domain = $this->container->get("kernel")->getDomain() and $this->setActiveHost($domain);
```

This is line 75-80

```
    if (isset($this->hostConfig[$activeHost])) {
        $this->activeHost = $activeHost;
    } else {
        $this->container->get('logger')->critical("[MultiDomain/Settings] - Unable to set Active Host.");
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Cannot find host %s for this eDirectory installation', $activeHost));
    }
```

Symfony 2.8, PHP 5.6.27

Answer (score 1):

I change the following line in `app/config/domain.yml`

From

```
multi_domain:
    hosts:
        staging.wisher.com:
```

To

```
multi_domain:
    hosts:
        localhost:
```